# how to create a process in Aem as a cloud which needs to be synchronously modified by users

Tags: java, synchronization, cloud, aem

we are trying to create a plugin in aem as a cloud. we are running into a issue where there is an asset which is available to all users but at one time can be processed by one user only. we are running into synchronicity issues where multiple users are able to process the same asset and plugin runs into issues. in aem on prem the synchronized key word could handle it but in cloud what what be the correct mechanism to handle this? so that only one user exclusively gets the lock of that assets and the other users get the information that the asset has already been locked?
i.e we  need synchronisation between pods to process an event only once

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using the check-in and checkout options in AEM? That effectively locks an asset from other users: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-64/assets/managing/check-out-and-submit-assets.html?lang=en#managing

Comment: This is for a custom functionality not an asset checkout. we create an object and would like to freeze and unfreeze it